# Count rows of a table using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, count

I was wondering, what is the best way to count the rows of a table with PHP using PDO?

Here is what I have, but not getting anything for `$count`.

```
$count = $con -> query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_descr")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $count[0];
if (count($count)>0)
{
$subStatus = "The email introduced is already in our database.";
}
```

Comment: You want to do `count($count)`?  It's returning an INT not an Array right?  What is result of var_dump($count); after calling the query?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use the PHP count() function on the array returned by fetch().  The count has already been calculated in SQL, so you want the *value* stored in the result, not the count of results.

Here's how I would write it:

```
$countStmt = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_descr");
if ($countStmt === false) {
  // do something to report the error
}
$count = 0;
while ($row = $countStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
  $count = $row[0];
}
if ($count > 0)
{
  $subStatus = "The email introduced is already in our database.";
}
```

*Always* check that the return value from query() is a valid PDOStatement.  Any error causes it to return `false`, and the scalar value `false` is not an object with a fetch() method. 
In other words, you can't make the call in a fluent interface manner (`$con->query()->fetch()`), because query() is not guaranteed to return an object.

Comment: Explain anonymous downvote please. Perhaps I can improve this answer if you say why you think it's wrong or doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @NullPointer, All the answers on this thread got one downvote.  I'm guessing that all the downvotes came from a single user.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM `item_descr`")
             ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $count['num'];

if ( $count['num'] > 0 )
{
  $subStatus = "The email introduced is already in our database.";
}
```

would work.
If you do a COUNT in your query, you will ALWAYS have just ONE result, namely the number of rows. So count( $result) will always give you 1. In my example I use the COUNT from the query.

Comment: this code is too dirty. can you please make it at least without throwing errors?

Comment: One possible fatal error is if query() returns `false`, which is not an object.  The fluent interface is not safe to use in this case.